# Unable to Access http://svn.xfire.codehaus.org/

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink, xfire

In Eclipse Plugin, while trying to add - xfire - http://svn.xfire.codehaus.org/ - as provided in the steps given at http://xfire.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin  getting the below Error .

```
Network connection problems encountered during search.
  Unable to access "http://svn.xfire.codehaus.org/".
    Error parsing site stream. [Premature end of file.]
    Premature end of file.
    Error parsing site stream. [Premature end of file.]
    Premature end of file.
```

I have my computer connected to internet, but i dont have the admin access, previously i could able to add other Eclipse Plugins successfully

Answer (score 0):

The instructions actually say http://dist.codehaus.org/xfire/update/ which is an Eclipse update site.